# Changing UITextfield from Non-Editable to Editable - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to have two non-editable `UITextField` display *name* and *age*.  I have an **Edit** `UIBarButtonItem` in my Navigation Bar that I want to be able to trigger the `UITextField` to be editable when that button is pressed.

In my Interface Builder, I have the User Interaction Enabled option unchecked for the two UITextFields.  Do I need to add `ageText.UserInteractionEnabled = true`? I'm at a loss here.

```
class UserProfileVC: UIViewController, 
UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var infoBorder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageText: UITextField!

    var textFields:[UITextField] = []

    @IBAction func editButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        nameText.becomeFirstResponder()
        ageText.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        var currentTextField = textFields[0]

        if (currentTextField == textField) {
            currentTextField = textFields[1]
            currentTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            currentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a Bool Variable. Set it to 'false' then when the button is pressed you toggle it to 'true'. Depending on its state just run to different methods which essentially allows you to edit or not.

Something like this:

```
var editTextFieldToggle: Bool = false

@IBoutlet var textFieldToggle: UIButton!

@IBAction func textFieldToggle_Action(sender: UIButton){

    editTextFieldToggle = !editTextFieldToggle //switches button ON/OFF

    if editTextFieldToggle == true {
        textFieldActive()

    } else {
        textFieldDeactive()

    }
}

textFieldActive(){ 
    //Turn things ON
    nameText.enabled == true
    ageText.enabled == true
}

textFieldDeactive(){ //Add anything else
    //Turn things OFF
    nameText.enabled == false
    ageText.enabled == false
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly without the last two textFieldActive() and textFieldDeactive() cases! Thank you!

Comment: I included those methods because lets say for example on your viewDidLoad/initial launch you want things 'disabled' you would just run that method and not repeat code. I just had to do that recently, but i had to disable 10 objects :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you want to do

```
nameText.userInteractionEnabled = true
ageText.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

and possibly

```
nameText.becomeFirstResponder()
```

when the edit button gets pressed the first time. You will probably also want to change the "Edit" button do a "Done" button. When the user presses the done button, you'll want to make sure you disable user interaction and resign first responder for both text fields.